# blocked [<SAMLRequest>] from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request

Tags: ios, web, single-sign-on, saml

we have developed an ui5 - Webapplication. For this application we implemented a sso scenario with saml over an ADFS.

If the side is loaded, the first oData (webservice) request is send with Authorization Basic... our backend determine, that no login is available and ridirect the request to the saml endpoint on adfs. This response is send back to the client to display an "popup" if the user is not logged-in in the sso domain, to put in the domain credentials. After send this credentials back, the original request is send again with an JWT instead of basic, that indicates a valid login.

Everxthing worksfine. Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, InternetExplorer, Android, Edge ... BUT the same Website in iPhone or iPad doens't show the "browser popup" to put in the domain credentials.

i get this error: blocked from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.

The Headers seems to be correct. Origin is set to fqdn of the website host. the $.ajax request is send with parameter crossDomain: true, xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}

What is the difference in iOS regarding all other browsers?

regards Micha

Comment: Your description of what you are doing is a bit vague. It also seems strange that you need XHR requests for implementing SSO with SAML. What do you mean by "domain credentials"? What exactly are you showing in the popup? The ADFS login page? What is basic authentication used for in your scenario?

Comment: "What exactly are you showing in the popup?" --> on an iOS device, which never belong to a domain, the browser should display a native credentials popup to type in the domain - user and credentials. If I use chrome and my notebook is not in a domain, I also get an native browser popup. .... the XHR: The first odata Backend call is a xhr request. What is the normal way to implement SSO / SAML from a javascript application with an java backend?

Comment: As I understand SAML, the whole idea is that users should send their credentials to the identity provider (IdP) only, not to the client / application / service provider (SP). The SP should have an endpoint, which returns a browser redirect to the IdP with a SAML request in the URL (This is ONE way of doing it). In this way, the credentials are never sent as a cross-origin request, and no cross-origin requests should ever be needed. The IdP eventually redirects back to the SP with a SAML assertion. This is why I don't understand where and why XHR comes into the picture.